# why is my available ram so little?

Tags: memory

any help will be appreciated

so my pc has been beeping 3 times during startup (3 long beeps with 1 sec pauses each), i googled and i read that i have some memory problem.

so i went up and look at my RAM and noticed that my available ram is not what its supposed to be

[image: picture]

I have 16 GB of ram (2 of 8GB) which only 8.5GB are commited out of 18.5GB
and the ram used is only 5.5 GB with only 2.4 available

And I am only using chrome, discord, steam and xbox game.
And my PC feels more sluggish and sometimes crashes when I play games like dota 2.

would love to hear some insight guys

Comment: There is a difference between having RAM *problems*, as indicated by the POST beeps, and *not having sufficient RAM*. It could be one of the RAM sticks is damaged, or not properly seated in the socket. Try shutting the PC completely and *carefully* re-inserting the RAM. Also try any of the many RAM tests (https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/), to see if that is the cause of the issue.

Comment: The "hardware reserved: 8GB" in the bottom right of your image suggests that the computer can see the RAM identifier but for some reason not use the stick of RAM itself. As DrMoishe says you should check that both sticks are properly seated.

Comment: Windows can only allocate 8GB. Your only using 70% of that which is the reason you see no performance impact

Comment: Using "... steam and xbox game. ". I can imagine both Steam and XBox reserving quite a bit of memory... trty excluding those from the "game" and see what happens.

Comment: You have one real problem, and one supposed problem, I think. The real problem is the boot codes. You need to look into that and solve it. Memory usage in Windows does not mean what you may think it means and there doesn't appear to be a problem there.